# Postgresql неверный подсчет количества строк в таблице

Tags: python, база-данных, postgresql, dbeaver

Столкнулся с удивительной  для себя проблемой. Использую БД Postgresql. Есть таблица с данными клиентов. Если сделать следующий запрос:

```
select count(*)
from client
```

Получаю количество 100062.
[image: Sql-запрос в DBeaver]

А если сделать фильтр в таблице id >= 100060, то результат будем иным:
[image: Фильтр]

Внимание, вопрос: как такое может быть?!

Свойства таблицы client.
[image: Таблица client]

В python-проекте считаю количество записей в таблице (используя sqlalchemy) следующим образом:
client_index = session.query(Client).count()

Результат совпадает с sql-запросом в DBeaver.

Comment: *как такое может быть?!* Элементарно. 4 записи были удалены. Или по какой-то причине AI-значения были пропущены.

Comment: Точно! Что-то я загнался)

Comment: @Akina подскажите, пожалуйста, как корректнее исправить этот "баг" ? При добавлении "недостающих" строк сыпятся ошибки:
SQL Error [23505]: ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "client_pkey"
  Подробности: Key (id)=(16) already exists.
  ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "client_pkey"

Comment: А, я извиняюсь, зачем? `id` - это же первичный ключ, верно? ну так он должен обеспечивать всего две вещи - уникальность значений и отсутствие NULL. Обеспечивает? всё, он все свои функции выполняет. Вы хотите на него повесить ещё одну функцию - непрерывной нумерации? а он против... Если нужна непрерывная нумерация - или делайте её в запросе, или заведите под неё ещё одно поле.

Comment: Спасибо. Вы все верно говорите. Надо будет подумать как изменить модель использования.

Comment: исправил запрос на получение актуального id с "session.query(Table).count()" на "session.query(func.max(Table.id)).scalar()".